# Implementation of barrier in Java

Tags: java

How can a barrier be implemented **with semaphores** in Java. Will the following pseudo code work? How can it be written using java Semaphore class.

`N` is the number of threads to be waited for at the barrier.
`EveryoneHasReachedBarrier` is a conditional variable.

```
Aquire(mutex)
m = m + 1;
if(m != N)
{ 
    Release(mutex);
    Aquire(EveryoneHasReachedBarrier);
}
else
{
   m = 0;
   Release(mutex);
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
       Release(EveryoneHasReachedBarrier);
   }
}
```

Comment: We are not going to do your homework for you.  Please post the code that you have already written and we'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Your pseudo-code doesn't use semaphores so it is not a solution.

2)  It doesn't correspond to the way that Java primitive mutex / wait / notify work.

3)  It probably wouldn't work anyway.  Since you release the mutex before acquiring the condition there is potential for a race condition.  (It is not entirely clear that this is the case because the semantics of your "primitives" are open to interpretation.)

Hint: What you need to do is read the javadocs for the Semaphore class thoroughly and then try to map them onto the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: thanks, just one question. can it be done using one semaphore object?

Comment: @Ajex - since this is homework, my response is as follows: "Good question.  What do **you** think the answer is?  Why don't you try and see if you can make it work with one Semaphore?"

Comment: I think a single semaphore variable cannot track multiple threads. It has no way to know which all threads came.

Comment: If there are threads A, B, C, D, I need to know if all have arrived. Not A, B, C, A

Comment: So try a solution with 2 semaphores then.

Comment: @Ajex - a thread cannot arrive twice.  The first time it arrives it blocks until the other threads arrive.

Comment: oh. ok. So one of the two you mentioned should be for mutual exclusion and the other for counting.

Comment: @Ajex - I didn't say you had to use either one or two.  I'm saying **try it out**.  The point of homework is that you learn by **doing** not by asking someone else for the answer!!!

Comment: I understand. Will try it out. Thanks a lot for your help. I feel motivated now.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or a [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Comment: Ah ... but the OP essentially wants to know to implement these using the Semaphore class ... as homework.

Comment: He can look at the source for those two and learn something useful in the process.

Comment: or not learn anything at all by just copying.  The best way to understand concurrent programming by going through the mental process of trying to work it out yourself.